# Unable to use Nvim-dap with codelldb

Tags: neovim, plugin, debugging

I am trying to configure neovim with **nvim-dap** to debug **C++** code.
I was thinking about using the **codelldb** debugger, so I installed it via **Mason**

My configuration looks like this:

```lua
local dap = require("dap")
dap.configurations.cpp = {
    {
        name = "Debug using codelldb",
        type = "codelldb",
        request = "launch",
        program = function()
            return vim.fn.input("Path to executable: ", vim.fn.getcwd() .. "/", "file")
        end,
        cwd = "${workspaceFolder}",
        stopAtEntry = true,
    },
}


local mason_registry = require("mason-registry")
local codelldb = mason_registry.get_package("codelldb")
local codelldb_path = codelldb:get_install_path() .. "/extension/lldb/bin/lldb"

dap.adapters.codelldb = {
    id = "codelldb",
    type = "executable",
    command = codelldb_path,
}
```

The problem is that once I try to debug a program, I get the following message:

> Debug adapter didn't respond. Either the adapter is slow (then wait and ignore this) or there is a problem with your adapter or `lldb` configuration. Check the logs for errors (:help dap.set_log_level)

Inside the log I have this:

```
[
  [ ERROR ] 2023-09-12T18:43:54Z+0100 ] ...nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:1426 ] "stderr" {
    command = "/home/soestilooo/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/codelldb/extension/lldb/bin/lldb",
    id = "codelldb",
    type = "executable"
  } "error: 'Content-Length' is not a valid command.\n"

  [ ERROR ] 2023-09-12T18:44:03Z+0100 ] ...nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:1426 ] "stderr" {
    command = "/home/soestilooo/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/codelldb/extension/lldb/bin/lldb",
    id = "codelldb",
    type = "executable"
  } "error: '{"arguments":{"pathFormat":"path","columnsStartAt1":true,"linesStartAt1":true,"supportsRunInTerminalRequest":true,"supportsVariableType":true,"supportsProgressReporting":true,"supportsStartDebuggingRequest":true,"locale":"en_US.UTF-8","clientId":"neovim","clientname":"neovim","adapterID":"codelldb"},"type":"request","command":"initialize","seq":0}Content-Length:' is not a valid command.\n"

  [ INFO ] 2023-09-12T18:44:06Z+0100 ] ...nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:1779 ] "Session closed due to disconnect"

  [ ERROR ] 2023-09-12T18:44:06Z+0100 ] ...nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:1426 ] "stderr" {
    command = "/home/soestilooo/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/codelldb/extension/lldb/bin/lldb",
    id = "codelldb",
    type = "executable"
  } "error: '{"arguments":{"restart":false,"terminateDebuggee":true},"type":"request","command":"disconnect","seq":1}' is not a valid command.\n"

  [ ERROR ] 2023-09-12T18:56:53Z+0100 ] ...nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:1426 ] "stderr" {
    command = "/home/soestilooo/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/codelldb/extension/adapter/codelldb",
    id = "codelldb",
    type = "executable"
  } 'Error: "Either --connect or --port must be specified"\n'
]
```

Which I don't really understand :/

Please help me figure out what is the problem here, I tried making my configuration as simple as possible so it wouldn't cause any errors.

Thanks for all the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I use this configuration in rust, maybe it'll help you

```
local dap = require('dap')
local mason_registry = require("mason-registry")
local codelldb_root = mason_registry.get_package("codelldb"):get_install_path() .. "/extension/"
local codelldb_path = codelldb_root .. "adapter/codelldb"
local liblldb_path = codelldb_root .. "lldb/lib/liblldb.so"
dap.adapters.rust = {
  type = "server",
  port = "${port}",
  host = "127.0.0.1",
  executable = {
    command = codelldb_path,
    args = { "--liblldb", liblldb_path, "--port", "${port}" },
  },
}
```

https://github.com/simrat39/rust-tools.nvim/blob/0cc8adab23117783a0292a0c8a2fbed1005dc645/lua/rust-tools/dap.lua#L8C1-L18C4

https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/zhokwt/share_your_neovim_setup_rusttools_nvimdap/